# How to use TidSMTP when mailserver has no smtp but ip only

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

i developed an application that sends email messages using indy (`idSMTP` + SSL).
The `idSMTP` properties I expose to the user are simply:

host

user

password

anyway in some cases the users have an internal mailsender that doesn't have an smtp address, but simply an internal ip (like 192.168.48.63) and no user and no password.

i tried to set host = id but it doesn't work.

Could you sugeest a solution?

Comment: smtp is a protocol on the tcp/ip stack. I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: i set IP as idSMTP.Host proeprty and it doesn't work

Comment: I think he's saying he can't use an IP address as the host property, and his local smtp server doesn't require a username and password.

Comment: You absolutely **can** use an IP address as the `TIdSMTP.Host`; I have an application that does exactly that (it uses a hostname the first try, and if an exception occurs it falls back to a secondary host that's an IP only for backup). You need to provide more information in your question details, because what you have here is simply wrong.

Comment: ok, this is good news, so probably i need to give the users other parameters to play with (like TLS). Do you deal with anonyomus smtp (no user/pwd needed)?